# Excel: Use a cell value as a parameter for a SQL query

Tags: excel, odbc

I'm using MS Excel to get data from a MySQL database through ODBC.
I successfully get data using an SQL query. But now I want that query to be parameterized.
So I wonder If it is possible to use a cell value (a spreadsheet cell) as a parameter for such a query.
For example, for this query:

```
select name from user where id=1
```

I'd like to get the id value from, say, cell D4 in the spreadsheet.

Is that the proper approach to parameterize a query? and how can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, Noboby can understand me, But I solved it in this way.

```
SELECT NAME, TELEFONE, DATA
FROM   [sheet1$a1:q633]
WHERE  NAME IN (SELECT * FROM  [sheet2$a1:a2])
```

you need insert a parameter in other sheet, the SQL will consider that information like as
database, then you can select the information and compare them into parameter you like.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the late question, I wonder i we can also use named function/named range/named cell as parameter ?

Comment: It seems this is exactly what we want, but I got an error saying that sheet is invalid object.

Comment: Doesn't work, Unable to connect, "Error while trying to connect" : Details: "Microsoft SQL: Invalid object name 'Sheet2$a1:a2'."

Comment: Yeah me too. I'm getting this "Microsoft SQL: Invalid object name..." error.

Comment: this just CANNOT work. i'm not sure why this is flagged as accepted solution

Answer (score 12):

If you are using microsoft query, you can add "?" to your query...

> select name from user where id= ?

that will popup a small window asking for the cell/data/etc when you go back to excel.

*In the popup window, you can also select "always use this cell as a parameter" eliminating the need to define that cell every time you refresh your data. This is the easiest option.*

Comment: This just threw an error for me. `DataSource.Error: Microsoft SQL: Incorrect syntax near '?'.
Must declare the scalar variable [...].`

Answer (score 3):

```
queryString = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE id=" & Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D4").Value
```

Comment: I guess I have to do that in a VBA script, right? I dont think I could type that expression inside the SQL window.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL is somewhat like the syntax of MS SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM [table$] WHERE *;
```

It is important that the table name is ended with a $ sign and the whole thing is put into brackets. As conditions you can use any value, but so far Excel didn't allow me to use what I call "SQL Apostrophes" (´), so a column title in one word is recommended.

If you have users listed in a table called "Users", and the id is in a column titled "id" and the name in a column titled "Name", your query will look like this:

```
SELECT Name FROM [Users$] WHERE id = 1;
```

Hope this helps.