# Refering Workbook cells from MS Query

Tags: sql, excel, ms-query

I have a query in a workbook which SQL statement is:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM table
```

Now, I would like to update query to filter data using criteria from my workbook as so:

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM table WHERE field3 = Sheet1!A1 -- Invalid statement!
```

How can I achieve this within MS Query (without VBA)?

Comment: I didn't find *official* answers but I guess it's impossible (in the same query). My guess is that you need to have two queries (one to obtain the value from Sheet1!A1) and then a second which will contain the value that you obtain in the first query (instead of a reference to Sheet1!A1)

Comment: How about this [method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285686/excel-use-a-cell-value-as-a-parameter-for-a-sql-query)

Comment: @PortlandRunner Good catch. It seems that I said something wrong. I didn't know that batch queries were supported in this case. I will remove my comment if LS_dev confirms that it works.

Comment: @PortlandRunner I can't make it work. I'm using Excel files as data source, and I think this driver doesn't support parameters.