# Updating an SQL query from a cell in Excel

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vba, excel

I'm building a dashboard in an Excel 2015 worksheet that summarizes sales activity from two tabs. Each tab has a dynamic PivotTable exported from an Advanced Find query in Microsoft Dynamics 2015, which includes an SQL database connection.

I'd like to be able to type in dates on this dashboard sheet (in corresponding "On or After" and "On or Before" cells) that can update the queries in both tabs' connections accordingly. The purpose of this is to avoid opening a connection's properties and update the SQL date string manually for each tab.

Comment: so what have you done. This is a programming site

Comment: How can this have been upvoted? There isn't even a question in this question post! @doubledell, please give worksheet and SQL details, show what you have tried that isn't working for you ... and pose a specific question.

Comment: Please refer to this site here for future Questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
@Topic: This Thread helped me alot with a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285686/excel-use-a-cell-value-as-a-parameter-for-a-sql-query