# Get data into Excel from SQL Server datasource depending on values in Excel sheet

Tags: sql-server, excel

Let's say in my Excel sheet, I have the following "table":

```
ZipCodes |
---------+
  4059   |
  5806   |
  4529   |
```

I need to get the data from a SQL Server view **WHERE** column `ZipCodes` has one of the values in my Excel table.

I want the user to be able to add as many `ZipCodes` as he wants, while not adjusting the query manually.

I've looked that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285686/excel-use-a-cell-value-as-a-parameter-for-a-sql-query) but I cannot get it working.

I'm stuck with passing a list of values to the sql query. It's working if I am passing a single ZipCode.

Sth. like this would help me:

```
WHERE  ZipCode IN (SELECT * FROM  [sheet2$a1:a2])
```

but that's breaking the query.

Comment: Where is this Excel document? Is it a static file, or is it going to be one that the user "supplies" to the data engine?

Comment: _but I cannot get it working_ Show us what did you try and which point you stuck at.

Comment: @Larnu the file will be setup by admins and will be supplied to endusers. They should review the data and they may add more zipcodes in the future.

Comment: *"supplied to endusers"*? So, it'll be located on their PC, in their email? Does your SQL Server have access to their local files (I assume not, and it should not). if they're updating the file, are they then resaving it locally? You can use things like `OPENROWSET`, but the file needs to be in a network location that the SQL Server's Service account has permission to access.

Comment: @Larnu I will create a new readonly user for only a single view. The server is accessible to anyone.

Comment: So, will the file be in a static location, and always in the location, for every user?

Comment: If static means it can only be used inside the same network the sql-server is in then yes thats the case !

Comment: No, by static location, I mean it's always in the same location. I.e. `\\YourFileServer\YourShare\ZipCodes.xlsx`. it won't later be `\\YourFileServer\YourShare\ZipCodesV2.xlsx` or have `\\YourFileServer\YourShare\Jane\ZipCodes.xlsx` and `\\YourFileServer\YourShare\John\ZipCodes.xlsx`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168623/discussion-between-felix-d-and-larnu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution here would be to use `OPENROWSET`. After discussion, it does appear that the location of the Excel file can and will change; this is fine but means we need to build a dynamic SQL solution, as `OPENROWSET` requires literal strings for it's parameters (no variables).

Firstly, I don't know what what version of the ACE Drivers you have installed. As a result in my code I am using  the drivers I have installed; which are the 2010 drivers (version 12). If that's not the version you're using, you'll need to change the value that I comment.

Normally, an `OPENROWSET` query might look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', --This declares the Driver. You may need to change this
                'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;;Database=\\YourFileServer\yourShare\YourFile.xlsx',
                'SELECT *
                FROM [Sheet1$A1:G];');
```

This'll return all rows from columns `A` through to `G`, starting at Row 2. Row 1 will be assumed to contain the Header (`HDR=YES`); if you don't have headers use `HDR=NO`.

The problem here is that we can't pass a a variable here. Thus we need to do something more dynamic. This gets you something along the lines of:

```
DECLARE @File nvarchar(500); --This would be your parameter
SET @File = N'\\YourFileServer\yourShare\YourFile.xlsx';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                ' + QUOTENAME(N'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=' + @File,N'''') + N','  + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                ''SELECT *'  + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                 FROM [Sheet1$A1:G];'');';
PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Now, finally, you want to use this data against your table/view. This, therefore, might finally look something like this (assuming your view is called `Customer_vw`, the data in the excel file in in column A, and the column in both datasets is called `ZipCode`):

```
DECLARE @File nvarchar(500); --This would be your parameter
SET @File = N'\\YourFileServer\yourShare\YourFile.xlsx';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'WITH ExcelZips AS (' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'    SELECT ZipCode' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'    FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                    ' + QUOTENAME(N'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=' + @File,N'''') + N','  + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                    ''SELECT *'  + NCHAR(10) +
           N'                     FROM [Sheet1$A1:A];''))' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'SELECT [YourColumns]' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM Customer_vw C' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'     JOIN ExcelZips EZ ON C.ZipCode = EZ.ZipCode --Note that EZ.ZipCode will not show in intellisense' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'WHERE ...;'; --You'll need to complete the WHERE here, and add any ORDER BY etc.
PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Note that I have `PRINT` statements in the queries. **These are your friends.** I (personally) suggest that you comment out the `EXEC` statements first, and just use the `PRINT` statements. Check that the output from the `PRINT` looks correct. If it does then run it, and if you get an error trouble shoot the output from the `PRINT`, rather than the dynamic SQL. Once you've fixed the non-dynamic SQL, propagate the changes to the dynamic SQL.

Hopefully that explains everything. If you have any questions, please do ask.

Comment: thanks alot ! Will try your solution and give feedback !