# Excel SQL Connection: Have a query update based on a cell value

Tags: sql

So, in short, I need to connect from data to a SQL query. I had not trouble doing this with a fixed query. I however, want that query to update based on values in certain cell. Since the person using it might not be familiar with SQL, Excel, or VBA, I was tasked with making the data update simply with the Excel refresh button. Anyway, super simplifying, I want to run a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    column1, column2, column3
FROM 
    table
WHERE 
    important_date BETWEEN [A1] and [A2]
    AND thing1 IN [list from A3]
    AND thing2 = [A4]
```

I saw this thread here: [Excel: Use a cell value as a parameter for a SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285686/excel-use-a-cell-value-as-a-parameter-for-a-sql-query) and it did not seem to answer my question for 2 reason:

1. One work-around seemed to require that the table itself be pulled into excel. The table in question would contain millions of rows, making his infeasible.
2. Some suggested a question mark (?) workaround, but entering ? for dates, lists, or strings simply outputted errors.

Given this, is there a possible way for me to do this? If so, how? and finally, if I can, how would I go about dealing with a blank list? For instance, if someone does not list anything in A3, I'd like the query to simply ignore the "AND thing1 in [list from A3] part of the code.

Thank you,

Comment: Could u please tag this questions with the technologies you are using?  This is simply not possible with just SQL as SQL only has 4 statements, (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).  None of them have anything to do with what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's for SQL Server Management Studio 17. Not sure how to add tags

Comment: i'm not sure this is a programming question.  What your asking is more of a real broad question on architecture and what technologies to use to do this from excel as the front end.  That takes a reasonable amount of programming skill with at least VBA, not just tsql.  If I were you i'd look into powerquery.  Powerquery by MS comes standard with excel from 2016 onward and has the ability to maintain connections with SQL server.  I use power query to do stuff just like this at our office.

Comment: How do I create a power query? I've seen it mentioned but I've never seen someone show where that feature is