# How do I parameterize an SQL query using Excel's "Get Data" function

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, office365

I am attempting to import data from an SQL Server instance hosted on Azure into Excel (Excel 365 desktop app)

I can get the basic query to work by going to `Data>Get Data>From Database>From SQL Server Database`

Lets suppose the initial query (entered into the SQL statement box under the advanced options in the dialog box produced by the command above) is `EXECUTE dbo.getClient 2`. This works and returns data correctly

What I want to do is parameterize this query to `EXECUTE dbo.getClient [Sheet1$b1]` in a similar way to that suggested here [Excel: Use a cell value as a parameter for a SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285686/excel-use-a-cell-value-as-a-parameter-for-a-sql-query) However attempting to do this gives the error "Microsoft SQL: Error converting data type nvarchar to int."

I then attempted to cast thus `EXECUTE dbo.getClient SELECT CAST([Sheet1$b1:b1] AS int)` but this gives the error "Microsoft SQL: Invalid column name 'Sheet1$b1:b1'."

So how do I parameterize Excel queries to an SQL server database? Answers which avoid macro scripts would be preferred if possible. I would like to be able to update the parameter cells in the workbook and then just go to Data>Refresh All.